# Symfony 1.1 Custom 500 Exception Access

Tags: exception, symfony1

In symfony 1.0 you can access the uncaught exception causing your custom 500 error page to appear through $this in your error500.php.  How can this be accomplished in 1.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's available in $exception in 1.1.